# Check Positive Float value in php

Tags: php, validation

I have a variable as **$x=some_float_value**. So how can **I validate or check that $x is a Positive  Float.**
For Ex.

```
$x=-4.99;
function checkFloat($x){
/////return true if it is Positive
}
```

Please Tell me how can i do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var) with `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`:

```
if (filter_var($x, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) && $x > 0) {
    // ok
}
```

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.org/0uKELh3q)

Comment: This bipasses 0 which can be either negative or positive.

Answer (score 2):

Check if it is a float with `is_float` and `> 0`:

```
function checkFloat($x) {
    return (is_float($x) && $x > 0);
}
```

Comment: This would return false if `$x === "4.99"`

Comment: Yes, `"4.99"` is not a float it's a string.

Comment: Numerically, 0 isn't usually positive or negative, unless you have such a case that handles it as such. However, unlike in ints, where these is only positive zero, many floating point representations support zero with the signed bit set. This means that in PHP a float with the value of 0 can be negative or positive, however in most cases PHP will ignore it, -0.0 === 0.0 for example. PHP will however sometimes leak the signed bit on output. (string)-0.0 !== (string)0.0

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the issue...

```
return $x > 0;
```

To conclude:

```
function checkPositive($x) {
    return $x > 0;
}
```

Comment: This will return true for strings that start with numbers.

Comment: And integers, and `true`.